# Calling C# function from XSL file

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xslt

I have a web application in which an aspx page uses an xsl file. I have written the following code inside the aspx page which checks whether plants are available.

```
     Private Function LoadPLants() As Boolean

        Dim objPlantXML As New XmlDocument()
        Dim objPlantNodeList As XmlNodeList
        Dim objPlantNode As XmlNode
        Dim strXML As String
        Dim strPlantCD As String
        Dim strPlantName As String

        'Get the list of plants to add to the dropdown
        objPlantXML.LoadXml("<ROOT>" & LoadPlants() & "</ROOT>")
        objPlantNodeList = objPlantXML.SelectNodes("//ROOT/Facilities")
        If objPlantNodeList.Count >= 1 Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If

        Response.Write("<SCRIPT language='Javascript1.3'>")
        Response.Write("function GetPlants()")

    End Function
```

If it is available it returns true else false. Now, I want to call this function LoadPlants() in my xsl file. Based on the value true or false, I have to display a hyperlink.ie; if the value returned by LoadPlants() is true, it means there are plants and the hyperlink should be displayed in the webpage,else it should not be displayed.  Below is the xsl code:

```
    <xsl:when test="TextilePlantCD[.=''] and CountryCD[.!='US']">
    <INPUT>

    <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:attribute name="name">txtTextilePlantCD</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="size">3</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="maxlength">3</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">text-alignleft</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">dTex_<xsl:value-of select="BOLDetailID" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="readonly">true;</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">width:35</xsl:attribute>    
    <xsl:attribute name="onkeypress">gotoNextControl(this);</xsl:attribute>
    </INPUT>

    <xsl:attribute name="onkeypress">LoadPlants();</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:if test="true">
    <img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">../Images/BookOpen.gif</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="OnClick">javascript:OpenPlantWindowForTextile('dTex_',"<xsl:value-of select="BOLDetailID" />" )
                  </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:when>
```

I tried several if conditions for this, but when I execute the code, the hyperlink is not showing at all. That means the if condition is not working. Can anyone please tell me how to fetch the value of a function in aspx page from an xsl file? I'm new to .net and xsl. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call C# methods in XSLT, but they would be embedded in the XSLT itself (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't think you can actually access functions in your aspx page. It might help if you explained what you are actually trying to achieve (by showing the input XML, and the output you expect), as you might not need to use C# functions at all. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that as it is stands, your current `LoadPlants()` function is recursive. The line `objPlantXML.LoadXml("<ROOT>" & LoadPlants() & "</ROOT>")` calls the function itself, and so will result in an infinite loop.